# Subtracting one data frame column from another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data frame as following:

```
text                 class.negative        class.positive       class.trust
<fctr>                    <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>

firmly believe...       11                   24                   3
when i thought...       3                    3                    4
fans of david...        11                   24                   12
just watched...         3                    5                    9
i was so looking...     16                   9                    10
```

Here's the code I used for data manipulation

```
clean.reviews = data.frame(text = reviews,class = get_nrc_sentiment(reviews), stringsAsFactors = T)
head(clean.reviews)
clean.reviews1 = as.data.frame(clean.reviews)
head(clean.reviews1)
```

I'm very new to data manipulation, and a little desperate with transforming data into the following:

```
class (class.positive-class.negative)  text
13                                     firmly believe...
0                                      when I thought...
13                                     fans of david...
2                                      just watched...
-7                                     i was so looking...
```

I realize that I might be insufficient in fully describing the situation, so I've uploaded the .csv file to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/79vpnos28b00hzn/IMDb.CSV?dl=0).

Comment: `clean$class <- clean$class.positive - clean$class.negative` ?

Comment: `class "c('matrix', 'character')"` is a giveaway that a dataframe only function  is being applied to a character matrix. try converting the matrix to dataframe first `as.data.frame(clean)

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` package will probably be the easiest way for this.

```
library(dplyr)
clean.reviews %>% mutate(class = class.positive - class.negative)
```

If you want to get rid of exisiting columns, replace `mutate` with `transmute`.

Comment: But I can't use mutate lol it says 'Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Comment: Make sure it's a data frame first.